# Tomcat CORS Filter: Why is the default list of headers in "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" so arbitrarily limited?

Tags: tomcat, filter, cors

Tomcat (7.0.50) brings a special filter that implements the CORS specification. In this filter, the default list of allowed headers is the following:

Origin,Accept,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers.

I know that I can replace that list by using the filter parameter “cors.allowed.headers” and specify my own list of headers. I know that. But I have the following questions:

- When this filter was created, why was the list filled with this –abritrarily- short list of headers? Why these headers and not others? Why, for example, isn’t the “cache-control” header in the list? How was this list chosen?
- If I want to define a more complete list, which headers should I include? There are some many headers to think about!
- Can I use a “*” instead of specifying a list? Is that something that the CORS specs allows?
- I know that the CORS specs defined this kind of list, but… Why is that necessary? Why can’t we just accept any header in the pre-flight OPTIONS step, instead of returning a 403 (Forbiden) if at least one of the headers requested by the client is not in the list of allowed headers?
- Why isn’t there an option in the filter to do something like this: 
  response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers")  ?

I’m puzzled. One of the users of my API sent the “cache-control” header in the  in the “Access-Control-Request-Headers“ list during the pre-flight step, and received an HTTP 403 error status. I can add this header to the list (using the “cors.allowed.headers” filter parameter). But what about next time some client sends another header that is not in the list?

Brian

Answer (score 1):

I spend hours trying to understand the CORS specification (http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/). Its really hard to understand.

The cors.allowed.headers list specifies which headers are allowed in the actual request.

In the preflight-request, the client tells the server via the "Access-Control-Request-Headers" field, which headers must be allowed by the resource. If one of these values is not in the cors.allowed.headers list, the request is rejected. This behaviour is specified in the CORS specification.

I think the Access-Control-Request-Headers is used to check if the requested resource really supports these headers. If not, the actual request cannot be satisfied. The fact, that Tomcat returns "FORBIDDEN" maybe is an implementation detail.

If you need some special functionality as mentioned in your last point, you may need to implement your own CORS-filter.